# Assigning curl output to variable only gives last line

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to do some tests to see if I can execute a shell script in a variables contents, similar to the Invoke-Expression function in powershell. I am getting the contents of the variable from curl:

`a=$(curl https://some.site/test.sh)`

however, whenever I print out the variable, it only gives the last line of the shell script.

Is there something I'm missing here? I'm using `echo $a` to print the variable.

Comment: How are you printing the variable?

Comment: does some.site/test.sh contain only carriage-returns, and no line-feeds?

Comment: also, note the difference between (quoted) `echo "$a" | wc -l` and (unquoted) `echo $a | wc -l`.   The former will print the actual line count.  The latter will print a result of `1`.

Comment: If i do `echo "$a"` (with quotes) it prints out the entire shell script which is what I was expecting to see, I was using `echo $a`. Also how do I tell if it has carriage returns? Its a linux shell script so I'm guessing it should have only \n

Comment: It doesn't have only CRs, that was just a guess, something to try.  Now you have first-hand experience of why you should (almost) always double-quote your variables.  the shell will enthusiastically word-split everything it can on any whitespace: spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.